# RegexStringValidator validation in MVC3 model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use a `RegexStringValidator` on a couple of properties:

```
[Required, StringLength(4, MinimumLength = 4), RegexStringValidator(@"AAAA")]
public virtual string ValueGuid { get; set; }
```

This actually accepts anything that is 4 characters long and not just "AAAA" which I would expect. Is there some magic I'm missing here?

Thanks
Anton

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the [`RegularExpressionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute%28VS.95%29.aspx) from the data annotations namespace and not the `RegexStringValidator`.

The `RegexStringValidator` is for validation of custom configuration properties and is not picked up for validation by the default MVC model binder.

The supported validation attributes located in the data annotations namespace are the following:

- Range – Enables you to validate whether the value of a property falls
  between a specified range of values.
- ReqularExpression – Enables you to validate whether the value of a
  property matches a specified regular expression pattern.
- Required – Enables you to mark a property as required.
- StringLength – Enables you to specify a maximum length for a string
  property.

There also two additional attributes supplied by MVC framework:

- Remote - Enables to perform client-side validation with a server callback.
- Compare - Ensures that two properties in a model object have the same value.

Comment: That would explain it! Thanks very much, it's now working as expected. I have no idea where I got that class from...